# Update score model field using JavaScript in Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have created a math game using Django and I use JavaScript in the backend to run the game without a page refresh. I need to update the score field after the game ends.  I can't seem to get that to work. The score updates on the frontend but not in the database so when the detail form displays the score is always zero.

JavaScript:

```
    let number1;
    let number2;

    operator = document.getElementById('operator').innerHTML;
    max = Number(document.getElementById('max').innerHTML);

    if (operator == '+') {
        number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    } else if (operator == '-') {
        number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        if (number2 > number1) {
                number2 = number1
                number1 = number2
        }
    } else if (operator == '*') {
        number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    } else {
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        numberx = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number1 = number2 * numberx
    }

    document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML=number1;
    document.getElementById('number2').innerHTML=number2;
    document.getElementById('tbInput').focus();

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keycode === 13) {
    

    if (operator == '+') {
        answer = number1 + number2;
    } else if (operator == '-') {
        answer = number1 - number2;
    } else if (operator == '*') {
        answer = number1 * number2;
    } else {
        answer = number1 / number2;
    }

    const checkAnswer = document.getElementById('tbInput');
    const value = checkAnswer.value;
    let playerScore = + this.document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML;
    

    if (value == answer) {
          playerScore+=1;
          document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML=playerScore;
    } else {
          alert('You are incorrect, the answer was ' + answer);
    }

    document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value = "";               
    document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('number2').innerHTML = ""; 
    if (operator == '+') {
        number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    } else if (operator == '-') {
        number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        if (number2 > number1) {
                number2 = number1
                number1 = number2
        }
    } else if (operator == '*') {
        number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    } else {
        number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        numberx = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        number1 = number2 * numberx
    }
    document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML = number1; 
    document.getElementById('number2').innerHTML = number2;
    document.getElementById('tbInput').focus();

    }
});
});
```

I tried using ajax but it didn't work. I am probably doing it wrong.  I am new at this.  Here is my ajax function:

```
    function register(score) {
    const csrfInput =  document.querySelector("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");
    const csrfToken = csrfInput.value;
    const score = Number(document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML);
    const data = {
        'score': score,
    }
    fetch(ajaxURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
}
```

Here is my view.py

```
    import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DetailView, ListView, UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Mathgame
from .forms import MathgameForm, MathgamePlayForm

class MathgameCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Mathgame
    form_class = MathgameForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class MathgameDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Mathgame

class MathgameListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Mathgame
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        order_fields, order_key, direction = self.get_order_settings()

        context['order'] = order_key
        context['direction'] = direction
        
        # get all but the last order key, which is 'default'
        context['order_fields'] = list(order_fields.keys())[:-1]

        return context
    
    def get_ordering(self):
        order_fields = self.get_order_fields()
        default_order_key = order_fields['default_key']
        order_key = self.request.GET.get('order', default_order_key)
        direction = self.request.GET.get('direction', 'desc')
        
        # If order_key is invalid, use default
        if order_key not in order_fields:
            order_key = default_order_key
        
        ordering = order_fields[order_key]

        # if direction is 'desc' or is invalid use descending order
        if direction != 'asc':
            ordering = '-' + ordering

        return ordering

    def get_order_settings(self):
        order_fields = self.get_order_fields()
        default_order_key = order_fields['default_key']
        order_key = self.request.GET.get('order', default_order_key)
        direction = self.request.GET.get('direction', 'desc')
        
        # If order_key is invalid, use default
        if order_key not in order_fields:
            order_key = default_order_key

        return (order_fields, order_key, direction)

    
    def get_order_fields(self):
        # Returns a dict mapping friendly names to field names and lookups.
        return {
            'updated': 'updated',
            'game': 'operation',
            'max': 'max_number',
            'creator': 'user__username',
            'score': 'score',
            'default_key': 'score'
        }
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        ordering = self.get_ordering()
        qs = Mathgame.objects.all()

        if 'username' in self.kwargs:
            username = self.kwargs['username']
            qs = qs.filter(user__username=username)

        return qs.order_by(ordering)

class MathgameUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Mathgame
    form_class = MathgamePlayForm

def score(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    mathgame = Mathgame.objects.get(slug=slug)
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    score = data['score']

    mathgame_score = Mathgame(user=user, mathgame=mathgame, score=score)
    mathgame_score.save()

    response = {
        'score': score
    }
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Comment: Share your `views.py` code. The function or class based view you are using to update the model

Comment: share your the view that receives that Post request. Also where exactly and how do you put the score sent from the back on the template?